# Delete/remove orphaned users and their schema from server/database

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, permissions

I'm new to the role of being a SQL Server DBA for SQL Server 2008 R2.

I need help on how to find out orphaned users in SQL Server and how to delete/remove the orphaned users and their corresponding schema from the database.

Please provide a step by step solution.

Answer (score 0):

1. To find out the orphan users of a database say "ABC", you need to query below on that database:i.e

   ```
   USE ABC

   sp_change_users_login @Action='Report'
   ```
2. This will list out all the orphan database users for that database. In order to resolve the orphan users, use [sp_change_users_login](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms174378(v=sql.105).aspx), with query below

   ```
   USE ABC

   sp_change_users_login
       @Action='update_one',   
       @UserNamePattern='database_user_name_comes_here', 
       @LoginName='login_name_comes_here'
   ```

Also, suggested reads: [How To Avoid Orphaned Database Users with SQL Server Authentication](http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/glenn/how-to-avoid-orphaned-database-users-with-sql-server-authentication/) and [Fixing Orphan users](https://redmondmag.com/Articles/2008/12/01/A-Fix-for-Database-Orphans.aspx)